# Script to speed up start of WCF Service on IIS 6

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-6

I have an application running on IIS 6 and the application also makes use of WCF Web Services, which when the IIS has been started or restarted and the user uses the Web Service for very first time or first call, it takes ages for a response to a call to come back - 54 seconds.

Whilst I understand the problem that the issue is to with compiling the code and getting services started; I would like to know if there is a simple way that when IIS 6 is started or re-started that the users can use the web service and only have to wait a few seconds - say 6 seconds.

Is there a simple way to do this - is there a simple script that can be run? If so, can someone show a script that I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/0ea5047f-cd7a-4de8-bc42-338855f376ea/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with IIS 6 we used very silly but working approach. We had simple console application which just pinged the application (or service directly on some operation which did nothing) and we scheduled this application in windows task scheduler to run every few minutes. I saw this approach in several companies during past years so I took it as "a standard way".

Comment: Thanks for that, but I have some other questions relating to this, which I will raise as a new question

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but here is a web page describing what someone did to speed up a web app which was taking .... 54 seconds to start when cold!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amolravande/archive/2008/07/20/startup-performance-disable-the-generatepublisherevidence-property.aspx

Perhaps you have the same issue.